# Add parent post to Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules, custom-post-type-archives

how can i add a parent post to my custom post type ?

I found an example :

```
function codex_custom_init() {
// Our People
$people_label = array(
    'name' => 'People',
    'singular_name' => 'People',
    'add_new' => 'Add People',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add New People',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit People',
    'new_item' => 'New People',
    'all_items' => 'All People',
    'view_item' => 'View People',
    'search_items' => 'Search People',
    'not_found' => 'No People found',
    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No People found in Trash',
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'People',
);
$people_args = array (
    'labels' => $people_label,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'our-people'),
    'capability_type' => 'page',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/icons/people.png',
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt','page-attributes'),
);

register_post_type('people', $people_args);}
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `hierarchical` property of the post type to `true` let’s you set parent posts for them:

```
'hierarchical' => true,
```

Comment: I updated to true, but also i doesn't have the dropdown for parent post.
It's work only for Categories